# Hiding a div with jquery from a modal window

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I'm currently stuck as I'm trying to hide a div onclick.  I can hide the div when using the delete icon within the same div; however, when I try to hide the div after opening a modal window it does not work.  Please find my code below:

```
<section class="images">
<div class="image-listing"><a href="individual.html">
<div class="image-mask"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x480"      alt="test image">
<div class="image-bar-top">
<div class="image-like"><img src="img/like_off.png"></div>
<div class="image-delete"><a href="#delete"><img src="img/delete.png">    </a></div>
</div>
<div class="image-bar-bottom">
<div class="image-bar-text"><div class="price"><b>$350,000</b> 4BD |    3BA</div><div class="notification"></div><div class="showing"><a   href="#show"><img src="img/show.png"></a></div>
    <div class="image-bar-details">Test | </div><div class="image=bar-   address">Address</div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="image-listing"><a href="individual.html">
<div class="image-mask"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x480"  alt="test image">
<div class="image-bar-top">
<div class="image-like"><img src="img/like_off.png"></div>
<div class="image-delete"><a href="#delete"><img src="img/delete.png">   </a></div>
</div>
<div class="image-bar-bottom">
<div class="image-bar-text"><div class="price"><b>$350,000</b> 4BD |   3BA</div><div class="notification"></div><div class="showing"><a   href="#show"><img src="img/show.png"></a></div>
    <div class="image-bar-details">Test | </div><div class="image=bar- address">Address</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</a>
</div>
</section>

<div id="delete" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close-delete">X</a>
    <section class="content-delete">
        <h1>are you sure?</h1>
        Delete This
        <ul>
            <li class="itemdelete">remove</li>
            <li><a href="#close">cancel</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried this, but I can't get it to work:

```
$('.images').on('click', '.itemdelete', function() {
$(this).closest('.image-listing').remove();
});
```

Comment: So far I see there is no way to know what `.image-listing` you're trying to delete. Please provide more details since it's not clear. Modal dialog is not connected with section containing  `.image-listing` tags

Comment: i don't see `.itemdelete` inside of `.images`

Comment: The modal dialog box is connected to the image-listing div via the <a href="#delete">, which opens the dialog modal.  Then I want to hide the image-listing div after the delete button is pushed in the modal dialog.